# FCM production APN not working

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using Firebase and FCM, APN was working perfectly in development mode.

After i upload the app to the app store successfully, APN was not working anymore. (**Unable to receive any push notification on iOS devices**)

Then I uploaded the production certificate to the firebase console accordingly as below: -

**APN Certificates on firebase console:**
[image]

I researched and found out my iOS app build settings is incorrect as below:-

**Initial Build Settings :-**
[image]

Then i configure my settings to screenshot below :-

**Current Build Settings :-**
[image]

and i encounter the error during archive the project, but no error during build the project.

**Error during archive the project :-**
[image]
Can someone point me the right way to setup the apn **on production mode**?

Would be appreciated if any suggestion provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not an issue of your FCM Configuration. Change your General Setting of your target as per screenshot.

> Uncheck Automatically manage signing from General Setting and choose
>   right certificates for Code Signing Identity from Build Setting.

[image]

Comment: Can I not use automatic signing with push notifications?

Comment: @StephenPhillips You can use automatic signing for push notifications also but in this question I suggested only for this question to use manually.